# GitLab: Applying Commit Message Template to One Branch Only

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, teamcity, webhooks

I'm looking for a way to set a Commit Message Template for the `develop` branch in a GitLab repository.

If I understand correctly, the GitLab UI allows setting a Commit Message Template for the *entire* repository. But I need it for my *specific* `develop` branch.

**pre-receive hook:**

I created a `pre-receive` hook file and tested.

```
#!/bin/sh

merge_commit_msg_pattern='^Merge #[0-9]{6}:\s.{5,}'

while read oldrev newrev refname; do
  if [[ $refname = "refs/heads/develop" ]]; then
    commit_msg=$(git log --format=%B -n 1 $newrev)
    echo "$commit_msg" | grep -q -P "$merge_commit_msg_pattern"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "Error: Invalid merge commit message format '$commit_msg'"
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
done
```

It works on my local machine.

Our team uses self-hosted GitLab. Unfortunately, the company security policy doesn't allow us to modify the file system of the GitLab repository. That's why it's not possible to put this custom pre-receive file.

**GitLab WebHook:**

We use GitLab + TeamCity. I tried setting up a GitLab WebHook, but I couldn't because GitLab can only send the Authentication Token in the URL. TeamCity receives the Authentication Token via HTTP Request Header.

---

Is there another way to set the Commit Message Template for a specific branch?